# How to convert a Buffer to audio/Webm-Opus and play it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I'm fetching a Audio file from API and convert it to a buffer.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
```

Then I send it via websocket (socket.io) to the client:

```
socket.emit("audioFile", buffer);
```

Then I try to play it with:

```
    async function playOpusWebM(buffer: Buffer) {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // Decode the Opus-encoded data
    const decodedData = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer);

    // Create a new buffer source node
    const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = decodedData;

    // Connect the buffer source node to the audio context output
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);

    // Start playing the audio
    source.start();
  }
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.
```